# Keep the same settings even after updating ClickOnce app

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have a WPF app deployed by ClickOnce. The issue is when user chooses "Remember my username," it'll store their username in Properties.Settings.Default.Username for the next login, but after updating the app, the stored username is gone. Is there a way to keep these information?